# How to make global planner avoid certain regions when planning?

Tags: ros, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the laser scanner (RPLIDAR A2) on my robot is located very high from ground (almost 6 feet). In the area where the robot will operate, there is a region that is bounded by walls with height of about 4 feet. When I map the area, these obstacles are not detected by the laser scanner and so are specified as free space and the global planner makes paths through this region. How can I tell the global planner to avoid this region?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280327/how-to-make-global-planner-avoid-certain-regions-when-planning?/) by [HM Mehrab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33359/hm-mehrab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An easy way to do that (I've done this in the past with success) is to draw black lines, squares, or some shape over the areas of the map that you don't want your planner to make paths through.

**Update:**

I had the opposite problem as you. Low laser catching only table/desk legs. The planner would plan through the table/desks because the legs were far enough apart for my robot to navigate between them except the tables/desks where in the way. I put black rectangles where the tables/desks are and localization still worked along with the planner no longer planning paths through the tables/desks.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HM Mehrab](https://answers.ros.org/users/33359/hm-mehrab/) on 2018-01-19**:
Will that mess with localization though? If I paint the region black, but the laser scanner reports that there is no obstacle, won't AMCL / Laser Scan Matcher get confused?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-19**:
I guess the answer is: it depends. Make a copy of your map and yaml file. Add the black boxes in the copy of your map and see if it works.